# Network outage when machine on internal ipsec secured net crashes

Tags: networking, debian, racoon

We have 3 machines (Debian Jessie), each having 2 network interfaces.
One interface is connected to the internet, the other to an internal net which is encrypted via ipsec/racoon.
One of the machines is starting to fail, and whenever it crashes the internet connection on the other machines begin to fail.

I'm guessing that it is some kind of network buffer issue, but I don't know how I could verify this, or how I could fix it.

```
                          |
   /--------------[internet switch]-----------------\
   |                      |                          |
[server 1]           [server 2]                   [server 3]
    |                    |                           |
    \------------------[switch]----------------------/
```

The connection between server 1 and server 2 is encrypted with racoon/ipsec (mandatory).
Connctions between VMs on server 2 are encrypted likewise.

Server 2 crashes with some kind of kernel panic (only got a screenshot from the lower half of the stacktrace).
~20 minutes later server 1 can't be reached any more - but it is still alive and when server 2 is rebooted server 1 is back online.
The last time this happened one VM on server 3 showed the same symptoms - however, after trying to start a console (xen) it was reachable again.